# How to make a Animation (Tinder-Like Swipe) with the Draggable Widget who overlap others Widgets?

Tags: dart, flutter

I’m trying to implement a feature similar to the tinder Swipe.
For this I tried to use the Draggable Widget which seemed to be a « good idea ».

So when a I touch and drag my Draggable, the widget is on top of everything (probably via an OverlayEntry).
But I want also provide a button that will animate and reproduce the Swipe behavior.
But the issue is that when I animate my Draggable it is being other UI elements, not above like when the widget is dragging.

What are my options ? How can I simulate the equivalent of the user drag ?

Comment: take a look at this package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_swiper

Comment: Thanks for the package, I'll take a look. At first sight it seems to be like a PageView. I need to drag the widget outside of the screen and remove it form the stack. Here this look more like a carousel. This is not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I have made a tinder like swipable UI before. I used a transform widget and gesture detector widget.